# DNS on my domain controller not working

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-controller, windows-server-2019

The DNS server on my Windows Server 2019 AD domain controller has completely crapped out, and I cannot even find anything that remotely addresses my issue.  When logging into the DNS GUI, my server is marked out and almost all the right-click options are grayed out:

[image]

Is it possible to rebuild the DNS server?  If not, is spinning up another server (or 2), replicating to the new servers, and retiring this one would be a great option; but I am not sure if that is possible with corrupted DNS (I didn't want to try it and get stuck with a bigger issue).

Comment: That icon represents that you are connected to the DNS server but the credentials you used to launch the DNS MMC doesn't have permissions to manage the server. What user account are you logged on to the server with or are connecting to the DNS MMC with?

Comment: That does explain a lot.  It is a Domain Admin account, but there have been some replication issues between the DCs.  The corrupted AD server is currently shut down because it was causing login issues.